# How does Tony Stark control his nano suit?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the *Avengers: Infinity War* movie Iron Man does battle with Thanos.

We see Tony fighting hand-to-hand, and Iron Man is morphing his suit in real time. Creating blades and such.

How can Iron Man control his nano-suit morphing with such speed? As it seems to morph at will, but we're not told how this is possible.

Comment: We knows that Tony worked a lot with AI. It would make sens that there is an AI involved in it.

Comment: The same way he controls everything in his suit.....not sure why this would be different.

Comment: @Paulie_D With fixed equipment it would be on/off, with the morphing nano-suit it appears to be able to form any shape at will, creating a more complex interface. Perhaps the forms are pre-programmed?

Comment: Congrats on asking the 100th infinity war question! :D

Comment: How does Tony Stark control his nano suit? *Very carefully.*

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## With thought control

Per this [**answer**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87661/how-does-tony-stark-control-the-hulkbuster-suit) at Science Fiction & Fantasy

> Tony Stark uses something called *brain computer interface* that translates brain EEG signals to control machines. So if Tony needs to move the suit's arm he just needs to think about moving it. This technology currently is very slow and not advanced as Tony has but it might get to that level in future. The electrodes of the EEGs are shown in *Avengers* and *Iron Man 3* many times.

[image]

Since then advances in Iron Man armour have removed the need for external electrodes and they are, presumably, nano sized now as per the rest of the armour and *enhanced*, with AI compatability.

Comment: ... or he simply skipped the middle man and had the electrodes installed directly in the brain. If the risks are low enough, that'd be totally in character for a tech-guy like Stark :P People already use brain implants, though nowhere near as capable.

Comment: That also explains Spiderman's comment on how intuitive the Iron Spider suit feels. He didn't have any nodes in his brain but the suit picked up his brain waves another way.

Comment: Pretty much any Stark illustrated in any superhero story has developed tech at least 100 years ahead of the competition (just watched the Captain America movie last night, Howard Stark invented flying cars during WWII). It wouldn't be unreasonable to assume that Stark's BCI would be something we'll probably have by the early 2100s.

Answer (score 0):

Since he 80's comics, Stark used telepresence, neuro interface. Your thoughts, make it do things.[image]